# How to pass a parameter to JSHint with Syntastic

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-javascript, plugin-syntastic

I need to pass a paramter (`-extract`) to the jshint syntax checker such that it extracts JavaScript from HTML before checking. Unfortunatly I have no idea how to do that for syntastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntastic allows passing arguments directly to the checkers using the `syntastic_<filetype>_<checker>_<option>` variable name format. It supports global (`g:`) and buffer (`b:`) variants with the buffer having preference over the global one. `filetype` and `checker` are obvious so I won't get in detail. `option` is what interests you. It can be `exe`, `args`, `fname`, `post_args` or `tail`. Put one after another they build the command that syntastic will execute. *See the help "link" below for more details.*

In your case you probably want to modify `args` for (I assume) the `html` filetype. You can put this global variable in your vimrc file to pass the command line parameter:

```
let g:syntastic_html_jshint_args="-extract"
```

Or using an auto command set it for a specific buffer. Examples:

```
autocmd FileType html let b:syntastic_html_jshint_args="-extract"
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead file.html,another_file.html let b:syntastic_html_jshint_args="-extract"
```

You can check more details with `:help syntastic-config-makeprg` or online at the [github repo](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/36ead6d75ce511a34d01f36051aa4c6d688f73bf/doc/syntastic.txt#L687)